# Is it possible to do ARIMA time series forecasting on 2D coordinates?

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, statsmodels, arima

I have the dataset in the following format :

```
time, x,y
2019-07-26 10:40:38.686 253 207 
2019-07-26 10:40:38.950 239 202
2019-07-26 10:40:39.150 228 202
2019-07-26 10:40:39.444 214 201
2019-07-26 10:40:39.643 205 199
```

I am interested in forecasting the evolution of these coordinates. I have read that `ARIMA` can be used for time-series forecasting.

I couldn't find any example of ARIMA for 2d coordinates. I write the following code :

```
 from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA
 train=data[0:170]
 test=data[170:]

 model=ARIMA(train, order=(2,1,1))
 fit_model=model.fit()
```

I get the following error : 
`must be str, not list`, which I am sure it arises from the fact that I am supplying 2D data as input. Do you have any suggestions regarding this?

Comment: Do you consider using other algorithms for your time series problem ?

Comment: @Rubens_Zimbres Well, I am a bit new to these methods. I have heard about VAR. I was previously using LSTM/GRU when I had an abundance of this data. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: You can use LSTM or even better, Temporal Convolutional Neural Networks, which is faster than LSTM. Usually one uses ARIMA for auto-regression, that is, you use the autocorrelation of your target variable with a time lag with itself. LSTM and TCN use dependent variables (X1, X2, X3) mapping to dependent variable (Y) - looks like this is your case. Arima maps Y to Y itself. For TCN, refer to: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1la33lW7FQV1RicpfzyLq9H0SH1VSD4LE .

Comment: @Rubens_Zimbres Thanks. I will check TCN out.